# Jquery on function firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This seems to be a well documented problem on stackoverflow and I have looked at numerous other entries, yet I can't seem to get a fix in place.

I have a link:

```
 <a href="#" class="edit-settings">link</a>
```

And a JQuery function

```
  $(document).on("click","a.edit-settings",function(){
  //do stuff here, including an ajax function
  }
```

I read one suggestion that you can use JQuery's `one()` function but this causes issues with content inserted into the DOM using the ajax. I also tried using `stopPropagation()` but with no luck.

How to get the event to only fire once, but reading any DOM changes in between?

Thanks

Comment: It can't fire twice unless the event is triggered twice or you bind to the event twice. It is most likely that you are binding the event twice. Therefore, the problem is elsewhere and can't be recreated with the code you have provided.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB. I'm a little confused as this is the only function that uses the "edit-settings" link as a selector. Does that therefore eliminate the binding of the event twice? If it helps, this function sits within a file called `custom-ui.js` that is included in the header. All contents of `custom-ui.js` is wrapped in it's own `$(document).ready(function()`. Is this the issue?

Comment: It could also fire twice if you have two nested elements that match the selector. But that's rather unlikely for a link.

Comment: Well, if that's the only function binding that selector, try putting a console.log() right before it. If it logs twice, that's your problem.

Comment: Just an observation and pithy semantics I suppose, but I'm assuming by the class name when a user clicks you provide some sort of edit functionality to whatever its attached to.   Instead of using an anchor, why not use an input button or styled span instead.    If you're not going somewhere with that link, its not really a link.

Comment: @anewvision What i'm suggesting is that you are somehow running the code in your question more than once, not that it exists more than once.

Comment: OK, problem solved. I can say, with some embarrassment, that the issue was being caused by a UI kit running the code more than once as @KevinB suggested. A data attribute in the link (which i regrettably did not include in the question) was triggering a div to appear in the ui kit, whilst simultaneously running my `custom-ui.js` function. Sorry for any time wasting and thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. I can say, with some embarrassment, that the issue was being caused by a UI kit running the code more than once as @KevinB suggested. A data attribute in the link (which i regrettably did not include in the question) was triggering a div to appear in the ui kit, whilst simultaneously running my custom-ui.js function.

For your information:

My link, before:

```
 <a href="#edit-nfc" data-uk-offcanvas 
    class="edit-nfc-settings uk-icon-button uk-icon-rss">
</a>
```

...and after (using a span to fix the problem. May be a bit of hack, but it means that I can keep the UI kit standard and my custom-ui.js separate. Event only fires once now)

```
<a href="#edit-nfc" data-uk-offcanvas>
  <span class="edit-nfc-settings uk-icon-button uk-icon-rss" data-uk-tooltip="{pos:\'right\'}" title="Setup NFC"><span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click","a.edit-settings",function(){
    //do stuff here, including an ajax
    return false; 
});
```

if this doesn't helped:

```
$(document).on("click","a.edit-settings",function(e){
    if(e.handled != true)
    {
        e.handled = true;
        //do stuff here, including an ajax
        return false; 
    }
});
```